# How to know the build plan and store path without building a Nix expression?

Tags: nix

`nix-build ... --no-out-link` gives a path in the Nix store.

- Is it possible to find out that path without actually building the expression ?
- Is it possible to find out the dependencies and the planned build operations without building the expression ?
- How could I find the answer myself ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man nix-store` has the answer, and in particular the `--query` section.

To know the output path:

```
nix-store -q --outputs $(nix-instantiate default.nix)
```

To know the build-time dependencies:

```
nix-store -qR --include-outputs $(nix-instantiate default.nix)
```

As for a build plan, the closer I get is to use the `--tree` flag.

Note that `nix-shell` exposes a `$out` variable too, so another possible solution to the first bullet point would be:

```
nix-shell --pure --run 'echo $out' some-file.nix
```

Comment: I think that `nix-env -qa --no-name --out-path hello` works for "hello", and could work with a file with the `-f` flag.

Comment: Thanks @noteed. NB You've misspelled nix-instantiate as nix-instanciate.

Comment: @hraban It seems I could do the edit. Sorry for the lenghty delay.

Answer (score 5):

The [Nix manual](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/), "Building and testing" section refers to [`nix-build`](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-nix-build) documentation, which in the last "Description" paragraph mentions it is a combination of `nix-instantiate` and `nix-store -r`.

`nix-instantiate` does not build. It only calculates the plan, in the form of a *derivation* and its closure:

```
$ nix-instantiate '<nixpkgs>' -A hello
warning: you did not specify '--add-root'; the result might be removed by the garbage collector
/nix/store/20bc2g6gfn44p9wk98s30pm346pmz0x9-hello-2.10.drv
```

However, I prefer to use `nix repl` to explore Nix expressions:

```
$ nix repl '<nixpkgs>'
Loading '<nixpkgs>'...
Added 8623 variables.
nix-repl> hello.outPath
"/nix/store/nic2bl8ry6vfyxr9717983d5b2l4sn1c-hello-2.10"
```

Its tab completion is very helpful when exploring expressions.